# Is $Q_n(A_n)=E(L_n A_n)$ a probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(\Omega, F, F_t, P)$ be a filtered probability space and $(L_n)_{n \geq0}$ a family of positive and $F_t$ adapted random variables.

I have to find the conditions for which $Q_n$, defined on $F_n$, as $Q_n(A_n)=E(L_n 1_{A_n})$ is a probability measure.

Then I have to show that $Q_n(A_p)=Q_p(A_p)$ ($A_p \in F_p$, $p<n$) if and only if L_n ($n \geq 1$) is a martingale

My attempt:

Is it sufficient to impose that $E[L_n]=1$?
On the second part

the if part (if L_n is a martingale) is easy to prove:

$Q_n(A_p)=E[E[L_n 1_{A_p}|F_p]]=E[L_p 1_{A_p}] = Q_p(A_p)$

how to prove is the only one condition??

Comment: What is $A_n $?

Comment: It is a generic $F_n$ adapted sequence, the exercise doesn't provide further details...

Comment: So there are two sequences, $(A_n)$ and $(L_n)$? Then how is $Q_n(A_n)$ defined? If you're supposed to show that it is a probability measure, then you must define what it does to a _set_.

Comment: $A_n$ should be just a sequence of events, belonging to $F_n$

Comment: Then $L_n A_n$ doesn't make sense. You probably want to define $Q_n(A)={\rm E}[L_n\mathbf{1}_A]$ for $A\in F_n$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function.

Comment: yes, that's right, sorry, I'll modify the statement accordingly

Comment: You replaced too much. $Q_n$ is defined on $F_n$, i.e. $Q_n$ takes a _set_ from $F_n$, not a function or random variable $\mathbf{1}_A$ as you wrote. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, exactly, +1 as soon as I'll have the privileges to do it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is sufficient *and* necessary that ${\rm E}[L_n]=1$ in order for $Q_n$ to be a probability measure on $F_n$.
2. Assume now that $Q_n$ is a probability measure, i.e. $L_n$ is integrable. Suppose also that $Q_n(A)=Q_p(A)$ holds for all $A\in F_p$ (for fixed $p<n$). That is, ${\rm E}[L_n\mathbf{1}_A]={\rm E}[L_p\mathbf{1}_A]$ holds for all $A\in F_p$. Since $L_p$ is integrable and measurable with respect to $F_p$ this means that ${\rm E}[L_n\mid F_p]=L_p$.